# Manifest Merger Failed issue in the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

Following are the error popping up in the output console. Always poping up new error. While opening any of class file there's error coming on the R. Cannot Resolve the symbol R. Please help me out.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-74:19 to override.
```

Following the `app:Gradle` of the project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo.skanda"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha1"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.msayan:tutorial-view:v1.0.6'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
//Library for Expendable Text View
implementation 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.0.0'


implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your following dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

is clashing with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

because both of them have the same attribute:

> Attribute application@appComponentFactory

---

You can fix the problem by using support version of ConstraintLayout with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Or change all of your support library with AndroidX library.